# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator -

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

here is my Logcat's Display Items. my app have no error but it unfortunately stopped

```
07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.delgence.timetracker/.AddTimeActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.delgence.timetracker/com.delgence.timetracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at com.delgence.timetracker.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:46)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)

07-12 14:43:15.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     ... 11 more
07-12 14:43:15.841: I/dalvikvm(1475): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-12 14:43:16.182: I/dalvikvm(1475): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-12 14:43:16.473: I/dalvikvm(1475): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-12 14:43:16.614: I/dalvikvm(1475): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-12 14:43:17.211: I/dalvikvm(1475): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-12 14:43:17.335: I/dalvikvm(1475): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-12 14:43:21.144: I/Process(1475): Sending signal. PID: 1475 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you have a NullPointerException at line 46 in file MainActivity.java . debug it and fix it..

Comment: paste the code of `onActivityResult()`

Comment: It would also have been useful to show us the code, and not just the error log. (And, to be entirely fair, you might want to paste a bit LESS of the log file next time.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your calling activity has been destroyed. Thus, called activity cannot return the result to your calling activity. This can happen if you, for instance, rotate your phone in the called activity, or you finished your calling activity.